# How to run hadoop application automatically?

Tags: hadoop

I know that a MapReduce program can be ran using the command line "hadoop jar *.jar" for a time.

But now the program is required to be ran a time for every hour in background.

Are there any methods to make the MR program be hourly submitted to hadoop automatically?

Adding `sleeptime(600sec)` in program perhaps is working, but it make the app run all the time.

Comment: 600 seconds will make it run every 10 minutes.

Comment: Learn oozie. You can schedule MR jobs with oozie.

Comment: oh my mistake. It should be 3600s. :P  Thx guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your saviour is [oozie](http://oozie.apache.org/). Happy Learning

Comment: Thank u Ramzy. Oozie is acctually what i need according to the project introduction.